# Bash how to check if variable is in range

Tags: bash

```
if [[ $entriestoDisp == [^1-9] ]]; then 
     echo "Invalid number of entries, choose between 1 to 9."
else
     #displays logs
```

Hi there, I am having trouble with this particular piece of code. I want to validate that the variable entriestoDisp has a value between 1 to 9 before proceeding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to compare using `=~` operator instead `==`

Comment: @codtex I was trying to check it with == and id doesn't work, do you know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression for range checking, unless you want to verify that `entriesToDisp` is indeed an integer before proceeding. Just use the regular comparison operators.

```
if ! [[ $entriesToDisp =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]]; then
    echo "$entriesToDisp is not an integer"
elif ! (( 1 <= $entriesToDisp && $entriesToDisp <= 9 )); then
    echo "$entriesToDisp not in range 1-9"
fi
```

This will work regardless of how many digits are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close:

```
if [[ ! $entriestoDisp = [1-9] ]]; then 
  echo ouch
fi
```